# How to revert the "clearsOnBeginEditing(true) effect" (remove older value at beging editing) on textField if it is left blank?

Tags: swift, textfield, nsnotifications, uiresponder

I have a function firing on two observers - `keyboardWillShowNotification` and `KeyboardWillHideNotification`, and what I basically do is resetting a text field while editing, emulating the effect of `clearsOnBeginEditing`. However, if the user left the field blank I want it to return the original value, before editing. Here's my experimental code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification) {

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification || notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {

            if textField.isEditing {
                let originalValue: String!
                originalValue = textField.text!
                textField.text = ""
                print("content while editing is \(originalValue)")

                if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
                    print("this is content on end editing \(originalValue)")

                        if textField!.isEmpty == true {
                            print("this is nill")
                            textField.text! = originalValue
                        } else {
                             textField.text = textField.text
                             print("found a value")

                        }
                }
            }
    }
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to implement keyboard delegates for this. This is easily acheivable using the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

```
var orignalValue: String = ""

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    originalValue = textField.text
    textField.text = ""
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
    if textField.text?.isEmpty {
        textField.text = orignalValue
    }
}
```

Note: Your view controller would need to conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and your text fields should have their delegates set to `self`.

Comment: @ISS my pleasure :D